# $\mathbb{C}$-points on a $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a "nice" scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$. We could
>   assume $\mathcal{X}$ regular and $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{Z}$ flat and projective, but feel free to change these
>   assumptions if needed. From $\mathcal{X}$ I can obtain first a
>   projective algebraic curve $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}}:=\mathcal{X}
>  \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, then a
>   complex manifold $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$.
>
> If I consider a closed point $P: \mathrm{Spec}(k(P)) \rightarrow
>  \mathcal{X}$, can I always find a complex point $P_{\mathbb{C}} :
>  \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}}$ whose
>   image, after composing with $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow
>  \mathcal{X}$, is exactly $P$? I.e. can I "complexify" the point $P$?

If I'm not wrong its being closed prevents $P$ from living on the generic fiber $\mathcal{X} \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$. Then the residue field $k(P)$ must be a finite field extension of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, thus it has positive characteristic. Specifically this prevents me from considering the tensor product of fields $k(P) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ which should be the residue field of the *"point induced by $P$ on $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$"*. But I'm quite confused about the topic...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that every scheme is over $\mathbb Z$ so that this hypoyhesis is empty.
And second that all your hypotheses regular, flat, projective, algebraic curve are irrelevant.

That said, the datum of a complex point lying over $P$ is exactly equivalent to the datum of a morphism $\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb C)\to \operatorname {Spec}(k(P))$ which is in turn equivalent to the datum of field morphism $k(P)\to \mathbb C$.
So the problem is: can $k(P)$ be embedded into $\mathbb C$ ?
The answer is "yes" if $\operatorname {char.k(P)}=0 $ **and** $\operatorname {trdeq}_\mathbb Q(k(P)\leq 2^{\aleph_0}=continuum  $, and  "no" in all other cases, like for example $\operatorname {char.k(P)}=p\gt 0$.

Comment: Thanks! In general it is not clear to me why the lack of $\mathbb{C}$-point over $\mathcal{X}$ implies the lack of a $\mathbb{C}$-point over $\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathbb{C}$. I mention this because I thought that base changing to $\mathbb{C}$ could have changed the situation of the existence or not of a "complexification" of $P$, but you seem not to consider it important.

Comment: Still, if I understand correctly then the following should be true. Let $p: \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a point in $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. Base changing gives the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p)$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$, but $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p \simeq \mathbb{C} / p \mathbb{Z}$ admits no ring-morphism to $\mathbb{C}$, thus this scheme has no complex points. If this is correct then I probably grasped a bit what´s going on here. Thanks again and $+1$!

Comment: Caro Giovanni, we have $\mathbb C\otimes _\mathbb Z \mathbb F_p=\mathbb C/p\mathbb C=0$. Also,  the only $\mathbb F_p$ point of $Spec(\mathbb Z)$ corresponds to the only ring morphism $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb F_p$, not the other way round as written in in your comment (there is no ring  morphism  $\mathbb F_p \to \mathbb Z $) .

Comment: Regarding the morphism $\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ I have only been sloppy and I didn't write $\mathrm{Spec}$... ...but for my claim that $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{F}_p \simeq \mathbb{C}\backslash p\mathbb{Z}$ I don't have such an easy excuse! Thank you very much again!

Comment: Prego, Giovanni!